# reset the data back to the original

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-visualization

I am working on angularjs and googlecharts. When user click on the legend, the data on the graph is hidden, when user selects all the legends all the data is hidden, i have a clear button which when clicked should get the data back. Right now i can able to only get last hidden legend value. How to iterate and get the data if more than one legend data is hidden. Any advice?

Working demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/kpgjpVA4Yp1KvNV7XkeZ?p=preview

When user click on the legend, data is hidden.I want to get the display data back by clicking on Clear button and i want to limit the user not to select all the legends to hide the data, atleast one line(data) should be shown.If user selects 3 legends and hides the data and selecting 4th legend icon to hide the data, it should display an alert message saying "ALL the DATA canot be hidden".

js code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['googlechart'])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    var chart1 = {};
    chart1.type = "LineChart";
    chart1.displayed = false;
    chart1.data = {
      "cols": [{
        id: "month",
        label: "Month",
        type: "string"
      }, {
        id: "laptop-id",
        label: "Laptop",
        type: "number"
      }, {
        id: "desktop-id",
        label: "Desktop",
        type: "number"
      }, {
        id: "server-id",
        label: "Server",
        type: "number"
      }, {
        id: "cost-id",
        label: "Shipping",
        type: "number"
      }],
      "rows": [{
        c: [{
          v: "January"
        }, {
          v: 19,
          f: "42 items"
        }, {
          v: 12,
          f: "Ony 12 items"
        }, {
          v: 7,
          f: "7 servers"
        }, {
          v: 4
        }]
      }, {
        c: [{
          v: "February"
        }, {
          v: 13
        }, {
          v: 1,
          f: "1 unit (Out of stock this month)"
        }, {
          v: 12
        }, {
          v: 2
        }]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "March"
          }, {
            v: 24
          }, {
            v: 5
          }, {
            v: 11
          }, {
            v: 6
          }

        ]
      }]
    }; 
    chart1.options = {
      "title": "Sales per month",
      "colors": ['#0000FF', '#009900', '#CC0000', '#DD9900'],
      "defaultColors": ['#0000FF', '#009900', '#CC0000', '#DD9900'],
      "isStacked": "true",
      "fill": 20,
      "displayExactValues": true,
      "vAxis": {
        "title": "Sales unit",
        "gridlines": {
          "count": 10
        }
      },
      "hAxis": {
        "title": "Date" 
      }
    }; 
    chart1.view = {
      columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    };
    $scope.myChart = chart1;

    $scope.seriesSelected = function(selectedItem) {
      console.log(selectedItem);
      var col = selectedItem.column;
       //If there's no row value, user clicked the legend.
      if (selectedItem.row === null) {
        //If true, the chart series is currently displayed normally.  Hide it.
        console.log($scope.myChart.view.columns[col]);

        $scope.reset = function() {
         $scope.myChart.view.columns[col] = col;
          console.log($scope.myChart.view.columns[col]);
         $scope.myChart.options.colors[col - 1] = $scope.myChart.options.defaultColors[col - 1];
}

        if ($scope.myChart.view.columns[col] == col) {
          //Replace the integer value with this object initializer.
          $scope.myChart.view.columns[col] = {
            //Take the label value and type from the existing column.
            label: $scope.myChart.data.cols[col].label,
            type: $scope.myChart.data.cols[col].type,
            //makes the new column a calculated column based on a function that returns null, 
            //effectively hiding the series.
            calc: function() {
              return null;
            }
          };
          //Change the series color to grey to indicate that it is hidden.
          //Uses color[col-1] instead of colors[col] because the domain column (in my case the date values)
          //does not need a color value.
          $scope.myChart.options.colors[col - 1] = '#CCCCCC';
        }
        //series is currently hidden, bring it back.
        else {
          console.log("Ran this.");
          //Simply reassigning the integer column index value removes the calculated column.
          $scope.myChart.view.columns[col] = col;
          console.log($scope.myChart.view.columns[col]);
          //I had the original colors already backed up in another array.  If you want to do this in a more
          //dynamic way (say if the user could change colors for example), then you'd need to have them backed
          //up when you switch to grey.
          $scope.myChart.options.colors[col - 1] = $scope.myChart.options.defaultColors[col - 1];
        }
      }
       $scope.serverId = chart1.data.rows[selectedItem.row].c[3].v;
       alert("serverid : " + $scope.serverId);


    };
  });
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <div google-chart chart="myChart" on-select="seriesSelected(selectedItem)"></div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large center" 
        type="reset" ng-click="reset()">Clear
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/NaxpbH5XbTo7CiTqAi8S?p=preview)? Here is [one with an alert](https://plnkr.co/edit/s9gmEQAPVo5EG3VeUriZ?p=preview).

First, set an array to hold the hidden columns: `var hidden = [];`

Then, your reset function:

```
$scope.reset = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++) {
    var hiddenCol = hidden[i];
    $scope.myChart.view.columns[hiddenCol] = hiddenCol;
    $scope.myChart.options.colors[hiddenCol -1] = $scope.myChart.options.defaultColors[hiddenCol - 1];
  }

  //$scope.myChart.view.columns[col] = col;
  //console.log($scope.myChart.view.columns[col]);

}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks Brian. Also as asked in my post above "If user selects 3 legends and hides the data and selecting 4th legend icon to hide the data, it should display an alert message saying "ALL the DATA canot be hidden". Can you please advice. thanks

Comment: Actually this one, as close as I can get for now. There is a strange artifact though on the last trend line. https://plnkr.co/edit/s9gmEQAPVo5EG3VeUriZ?p=preview

Comment: +1, thankyou. But unfortunately its not working as expected, it has to show alert and not hide the data.